# Image organizer based on categories or tags

Tags: images, information-management, duplicate-files

I'm looking for a program that has, in order of most important to least:

- The ability or organize large sets (multiple gigabytes) of images based on categories or tags
- A robust and *fast* search engine based on that information
- The ability to detect duplicates (either bitwise or by actual image comparison)
- Integration with Explorer (Windows) or Finder (Mac)
- Ideally runs on all OSes

This is less for photos of people and things that I've taken, and more for finding images that are good fodder for photoshop or usage on image boards. Any kind of face detection or those kind of features meant for real photographs is not necessary.

As an example of the perfect software, say I'm looking for an image macro - I would hit the upload field on my favorite image board, and the explorer integration would give me an option to search through my image library right in the file open dialog. I would enter "image macro" into the search field, and perhaps some tags like "happy" and "thumbs up", and would get a selection of matching images.

Is this a thing that exists?

Comment: I would recomment XNView but I don't think it has all the features, like detect duplicates. http://www.xnview.com/en/